# Light node: difference between IRI repo and iota.lib.java?

Tags: light-node, java

I'm interested in doing some tests as a light node and I'm currently studying the code.
What are the difference between the IRI and the java library (iota.lib.java)? Should I use or not use one of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run your own full node, you'll use iri (or Nelson, or both).

If you want to program something in Java that should connect to a full node (i. e. is a light node), you use iota.lib.java. If you want to implement it in JavaScript (in-browser or node.js) you'd use iota.lib.js.

Comment: I'm interested in a light node right now. I'll use iota.lib.java and I'll start doing some experiments :)
Any advice?